# How to display the array element to view

Tags: laravel

I have a problem regarding the return view('doctor_index', compact('result') on my contoller

here is my controller

```
public function index()
{

    $data = Auth::user()->patient;

    $data = explode(',', $data);

    foreach ($data as $key => $datas) {

       $result = DB::table('patients')->where('id', $datas)->get();

            foreach ($result as $key => $res) {

                $output = ' <h4><b>'. $res->patient_name .'</b></h4>
                                </p>Birthday: <strong>'. $res->post_date .'</strong>  Age: <strong>'. $res->patients_age .'</strong></p>
                                <p>Address: <strong>'. $res->patient_address .'</strong></p><br><br>';
            }  

         echo $output;

        // return view('doctor_index', compact('output'));
    }
}
```

at first i used echo $output; this is what it displayed

**Output of echo $output:**

[image: output of echo $output]

Now if i use the return view on the controller it displays

**Output of the return view:**

[image: output of the return view]

as you can see when i use the return view it only display the first element

My question is how can i display all of the elements to my view using the return view

my view code:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2><b>{{ Auth::user()->name }} </b></h2>
                      <p>Email: <strong> {{ Auth::user()->email }} </strong></p> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Patients</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="container">

                           <?php echo $output ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is because you have written the echo inside foreach
but when you return it to view it will return only one

Comment: i tried to echo $output outside the foreach it displayed the last element not all of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With functions and methods once it reaches the return statement it won't continue through the other loops. Instead you should pass the array to the view and loop over the array within your view. So your controller would look something like this:

```
public function index()
{

    $data = Auth::user()->patient;

    $data = explode(',', $data);
    $responseData = [];

    foreach ($data as $key => $datas) {

       $result = DB::table('patients')->where('id', $datas)->get();

            foreach ($result as $key => $res) {

                $responseData[] = ' <h4><b>'. $res->patient_name .'</b></h4>
                                </p>Birthday: <strong>'. $res->post_date .'</strong>  Age: <strong>'. $res->patients_age .'</strong></p>
                                <p>Address: <strong>'. $res->patient_address .'</strong></p><br><br>';
            }  
    }

    return view('doctor_index', compact('responseData'))
}
```

And then your blade template would look something like this.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2><b>{{ Auth::user()->name }} </b></h2>
                      <p>Email: <strong> {{ Auth::user()->email }} </strong></p> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Patients</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="container">
                           @foreach($responseData as $output)
                               {!! $output !!}
                           @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```